# mCustomScrollbar doesn't seem to work for horizontal scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/3LQJG/2/

Above is a JSFiddle demonstrating the problem. I invoke the `mCustomScrollbar` on the parent of the content holder which has `overflow` in the `x` direction.

However, you will notice that it modifies the width of the container, and the scrollbar is inactive.

How do I correct this?

Comment: I think your [external CSS](http://assets.msmu.me/css/combined_corporate.css) is unavailable, and you didn't include CSS for custom scrollbar, so it does not work.

Comment: @Gromo Hey, this updated fiddle should demo the problem appropriately. It includes the relevant scrollbar CSS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3LQJG/3/). Look at source code of mCustomScrollbar demo page and you will see that horizontal scrollbar requires:

1. `axis:'x'`
2. `advanced:{autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true}` - I don't know what is it for, but without it scrollbar does not work

Also, I've prepared [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3LQJG/4/) of [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) - just to look and try. Scrollbar style is based on container class. Different scrollbar types are available on [demo page](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your correct answer! I was wondering why the horizontal scroll was not working.
I modified a little bit as follows:

```
$(function(){
    var csObj = new Object();
    //csObj.horizontalScroll=true;
    csObj.setWidth=700;
    csObj.setHeight=300;
    csObj.verticalScroll=true;
    csObj.axis="xy";
    csObj.advanced={autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true};
    csObj.scrollButtons = {
        enable:true,
        scrollType:"pixels",
        scrollAmount:300
    };
    csObj.callbacks = {onTotalScroll:finishFunc};
    //csObj.theme="dark";

    $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar(csObj);
});
```

I think this style is much easier for better understanding.